# Какая среда разработки visual studio подходит для создания сайтов и разработки прикладного ПО на С#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста какая среда разработки visual studio больше подходит для создания сайтов и разработки прикладного ПО на С#?

Visual Basic Express

Visual Web Developer Express

Visual C# Express

Я просто не хочу ставить полную версию Visual Studio на один компьютер. Хочу поставить одну из этих программ на клиентский компьютер, а SQL Server 2012 на свой сервер.

Answer (score 5):

Возможно вам в большей степени подойдет MS Visual Studio Community, чем Express:
https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx

Точно так же он бесплатен и поддерживает весь необходимый Вам универсальный функционал. 
Если же важна легковесность, то самым легкм универсальным решением у MS сейчас является Visual Studio Code. Он так же позволяет работать с asp.net, но там есть сложности в полноценной работе с UI

Если же смотрите исключительно на Express, то в принципе возможно установить две редакции. Смотрите desktop и web

Comment: Вопрос задавался в 12м году, а Community Edition вышла в 2014м :)

Comment: Не обратил внимание. Code - так вообще свежий. Тем не менее Express часто упоминается во множестве испочников и вопрос может быть актуален пусть не для автора.

Answer (score 2):

Для веб требуется - Visual Web Developer Express
Для разработки прикладного ПО на C# - Visual C# Express
Согласно названиям )))

Comment: а первое: Visual Basic Express, тут вообще не причем)

Comment: Возможна ли установка обеих программ на одном компьютере? И реализовано ли в них подключение к удаленной базе данных SQL Server?

Comment: Установка возможна. А что значит второй вопрос? Для чего подключать среду разработки к СУБД?

Comment: среду никуда подключать не надо, коннектиться будет твой софт или сайт...

Answer (score 1):

Для разработки прикладного ПО рекомендую [SharpDeveloper](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx).
Конечно ему далеко до удобств студии, но во всяком случае в разы удобнее express версий.
Не знаю как у него поддержка для веба - но для декстопа очень ничего.